# Website somehow lost "force www removal"

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, url-rewriting

My website used to have "force SSL" and "force www removal". But now it lost "force www removal". To be more clearer, it is now "force www".

The related code in my .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

I did not change the above code at all. I had contacted my webhosting company, and they said the issue is in .htaccess.

If I have to point out a possible cause, it could be that a support staff (of my webhosting company) helped me change my PHP version. That probably is why two lines were being added at the beginning of my .htaccess:

```
# Use PHP56 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56s .php
```

But I'm not sure if that really is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code add the www. Use instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now all pages works correctly. I really don't know why the old code suddenly stopped working. I did not change them at all. Anyway, thank you!